# Using JS SDK API Locally

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, offline

I saw the documentation and notice that the SDK download link is live to esri server, can we download the SDK and setup in local environment? Please suggest?

If YES, how to change the config so that require loads the file from local.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you currently stuck? Have you downloaded the JavaScript library, and looked at the ReadMe?

Comment: I think your question would be more attractive to potential answerers if you could be more explicit about which download link you are referring to so that we know exactly the software that you are using or wanting to use, and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the ArcGIS API for Javascript (which I assume you are referring to) can be downloaded and hosted locally. See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_accessapi.html

The API download includes an install.html file with detailed instructions.